# как суммировать значения по одинаковым ключам объекта в таблице js

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, key

Существует таблица, вид данных :

```
let data = [
 {'other': 21, 'shop_tech': 244, 'quota_test':453},
 {'other': 24, 'shop_tech': 284, 'quota_test':573},
 {'other': 51, 'shop_tech': 224, 'quota_test':233},
];
```

Я подготавливаю результирующую сумму снизу таблицы так, чтобы меня не заботило количество столбцов присутствующих в таблице, так скажем универсальная функция, которая формирует итоги. Как можно сгруппировать данные всех колонок по одинаковым ключам? или это невозможно в силу того, что каждая строка уникальна? У меня один только способ дал результат - это создание переменных под каждый ключ и складывать значения, но если у меня 100 столбцов - это утопия. Прошу подсобить советами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как можно сгруппировать данные всех колонок по одинаковым ключам?

Например таким образом...

```js
const data = [
 {'other': 21, 'shop_tech': 244, 'quota_test':453},
 {'other': 24, 'shop_tech': 284, 'quota_test':573},
 {'other': 51, 'shop_tech': 224, 'quota_test':233},
];
console.log(res(data))

//
function res(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
      r[k] = (r[k] ?? 0) + o[k]
    })
    return r
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: Огромная благодарность вам !
А мне нужно больше читать документации для работы с объектами и массивами

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через reduce

```js
let data = [
  {'other': 21, 'shop_tech': 244, 'quota_test':453},
  {'other': 24, 'shop_tech': 284, 'quota_test':573},
  {'other': 51, 'shop_tech': 224, 'quota_test':233},
];
const keys = {};
for (let key in data[0]) {
  keys[key] = 0;
}

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (let key in item) {
    acc[key] += item[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, { ...keys });

console.log(result, keys)
```

Можно обойтись одной переменной, т.к. **reduce** мутирует объект, переданный как аккумулятор для начального значения

```js
let data = [
  {'other': 21, 'shop_tech': 244, 'quota_test':453},
  {'other': 24, 'shop_tech': 284, 'quota_test':573},
  {'other': 51, 'shop_tech': 224, 'quota_test':233},
];
const result = {};
for (let key in data[0]) {
  result[key] = 0;
}

data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (let key in item) {
    acc[key] += item[key];
  }
  return acc;
}, result);

console.log(result)
```